# Get The Employee who has taken Minimum days of leave

Tags: sql, oracle

Recently in one of the interviews I had given , I was asked question to

> write a query to find the employee with min days of leave in previous 3 months department wise.

The table structure was

```
EMPID | TO_DATE | FROM_DATE | LEAVE _TYPE | DEPT_NO
```

I was able to write the query

```
SELECT 
min(days) FROM (SELECT id ,(sum((TO_DATE-FROM_DATE)+1) ) days ,dept  
FROM emp_leave  
WHERE to_date  between  ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-3)  AND sysdate group by id,dept) 
group by dept  ;
```

but when I try to select the `emp_id` I have to add it in group by statement.

I was stuck there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the query should have been something like

```
 select dept, min(id) keep (dense_rank last order by days)
from (  SELECT  id ,
            (sum((TO_DATE-FROM_DATE)+1) ) days ,
            dept 
    FROM emp_leave 
    WHERE to_date between ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-3) 
    AND sysdate group by id,dept) 
group by dept
;
```

Well of course, in SQL you have a lot of different way to do this, but when it is about ranking stuff, the first/last function is very useful

Comment: @Khanjan you're welcome. I hope you understood how it works so you can re-use it if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 SELECT id
    ,(sum((TO_DATE - FROM_DATE) + 1)) days
    ,dept
FROM emp_leave
WHERE to_date BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, - 3)
        AND sysdate
GROUP BY id
    ,dept
ORDER BY days LIMIT 1
```

Comment: this will not give all the dept's emp..it will give one record which is having least no of days as leave